# Java 8 Concurrent Hash Map get Performance/Alternative

Tags: performance, java-8, concurrenthashmap

I have a high throughput low latency application (3000 Request/Sec, 100ms per request), and we heavily use Java 8 `ConcurrentHashMap` for performing lookups. Usually these maps are updated by a single background thread and multiple threads read from these maps.

I am seeing a performance bottleneck, and on profiling I find `ConcurrentHashMap.get` as being the hotspot and taking majority of the time.

I another case, I see `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` being the hotspot, although the mapping-function has very small latency and the profile shows `computeIfAbsent` spending 90% of the time executing itself, and very less time in executing the mapping-function.

My question is there any way i could improve the performance? I have around 80 threads concurrently reading from CHM.

Comment: Is your hasmap used more for reading values, writing values, both? It's very difficult to help you if we don't have more information about the algorithm itself.

Comment: You should [prescreen](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks) `computeIfAbsent` by an optimistic `get` to avoid the locking penalty on a read.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. for (reading at 3000 Rps) and writing would be roughly 100 rps. Ben Manes: can you please elaborate

Comment: If you say *"updated by a single background thread"* does that also cover the `computeIfAbsent` calls, because those are potentially-mutating actions.

Comment: Typically if you have a highly-contended shared resource like this, the most broad (albeit heavy-handed) kind of way to improve performance is to dice it up. Is there any way you could split that map into multiple maps where each thread reading it would know which one to look up?

Comment: As a very simplistic example, let's say your keys are integers. In that case, you can easily split your CHM into two: one for even keys, one for odd. Those read threads looking up keys can then quickly know which of the two CHMs to use, and the result is reduced thread contention.

Comment: #the8472, no computeIfAbsent is called by the reading threads, and as Ben pointed out it would be better to do optimistic get before computeIfAbsent, @Ike isn't that just map of map?

Comment: @AmmSokun Not necessarily, and map of map is less likely to help. You want some pre-existing knowledge of the key (ex: whether it is even or odd, the first character of a string, something like that) to determine which map to use so that only local memory for the thread is needed to determine which map to look up. If you have a map of maps, then you end up transferring heavy contention to the first map, and likely end up simply getting bottlenecked there instead.

Comment: @Ike my keys are String

Comment: @AmmSokun In that case, for example, you might have an array of CHMs (not too large) based on a hash of the string or even some modulo of the first character of the string. The key is that this array is precomputed, it is never changed (and thus can be lock/atomic-free). This might seem only subtly different, but it makes each CHM you store within it get lighter contention. Even a fast concurrent structure typically needs atomic CAS and pays some sync penalty when accessed across many threads (even for read-only use).

Comment: @AmmSokun `computeIfAbsent` pessimistically locks prior to reading and potentially computing the value. On a 32+ core machine that does appear to be faster under contention, but otherwise an optimistic read is much faster. This is especially true when there is a high probability of the read succeeding, such as in a cache. When it does flip, the difference is less noticeable so pre-screening is a net benefit.

Comment: @the8472 That's a good thing to look into but it's not so unnatural for `get` to show up as a hotspot here when being accessed by 80 threads concurrently. Concurrent data structures often use atomics as a cheaper form of synchronization, but the cost of synchronization still scales with the number of threads contending the same cache line for the atomic variable. With a contiguous style structure like the CHM, there will typically be a shared variable of this sort for the entire structure. So heavy contention here can still multiply the cost of this `get` operation.

Comment: We had a similar issue with `concurrent_vector` from Intel's Thread Building Blocks (C++). We got a little too excited by the fact that it's designed for concurrency and made huge ones that were being accessed by a boatload of threads (similar to this case). It became a hotspot. Solution: split it up into multiple vectors with pre-existing knowledge in each thread used to look up the appropriate one. Reduce the contention --> big speed up. I might be a little off on the architectural details of why that helps -- but this typically works.

Comment: @Ike my chm is not very big ( 5K keys only )

Comment: @AmmSokun Oh, that's extremely small. But I was reading up on CHM -- do you utilize the `concurrencyLevel` constructor parameter in it? That effectively seems to have a similar effect to dicing it up into smaller containers ('segments' in the source).

Comment: In jdk 8 that parameter is nothing but sizing hint, it isnt used anymore

Comment: @Ike, your understanding of atomics is incorrect. `get` only uses some volatile reads, which are very cheap on x86. Namely, they are normal reads minus compiler reorderings, i.e. no CPU barrier instructions involved. At 3k reads per second those should be a non-issue. As long as they are only read from there is no cache coherency or anything like that because the cachelines are in shared mode. (of course one can check with `perf` or similar tools)

Comment: @BenManes: I don't think that computeIfAbsent would not pre-empt a non-blocking get before trying to compute the absent value. Doc says ```For example, to add a count to a ConcurrentHashMap<String,LongAdder> freqs, you can use freqs.computeIfAbsent(k -> new LongAdder()).increment();``` I too use CHM for maintaining counters using the same style and don't see any performance issue there

Comment: @BenManes: Can you please share the snippet of Jdk 8 ```computeIfAbsent``` which pessimistically acquire the lock. I looked at the CHM#computeIfAbsent but not able to understand much

Comment: Just tackling it from a conceptual perspective -- not sure what the JVM does with `volatile`. But a concurrent structure of this sort needs typically needs a memory barrier of some sort (though it can be lock-free and still use atomic instructions -- that would merely cease to make it wait-free).

Comment: https://brooker.co.za/blog/2012/09/10/volatile.html <-- this one might be of interest.

Comment: Actually, the question says *"3000 Request/Sec"*. How many CHM method calls are performed per request? Since you spend 100ms per request the CHM calls should either be a small fraction thereof or it has to be more than 1 per request. In other words, the question provides very vague data, you're not even including your profiler output.

Comment: @Ike, that blog post is an extreme case because it tests volatiles under heavy contention, with multiple threads competing for the same cachelines for 100% of their instruction cycles. Volatile costs amortize quickly if they are interleaved with other operations or things accessing other, non-contended ones.

Comment: @AmmSokun The `else` block where variable `f` means found, the bucket chain uses `synchronized (f)`. Doug Lea [recommends](http://jsr166-concurrency.10961.n7.nabble.com/Re-ConcurrentHashMap-computeIfAbsent-td11687.html) the pre-screening optimization for machines less than 32-way, but having to look into the future the optimization was too short term for adoption.

Comment: @the8472 I see -- though this case might still be suffering from the heavy contention (teeny 5k CHM, lots of threads -- though I realized later on that it's diced up into segments). Though I'm with you that more data sure would be nice. 3k reads per/sec sounds like nothing -- I would think something is seriously wrong if there aren't many CHM lookups per request.

Comment: @Ben ah, just saw the synchronised keyword, yup mapping function is called inside the synchronised keyword (and that how they guarantee mapping function being called at-most once, although this should have been mentioned somewhere in java-doc), Pre-empt screening is the way to go then. Thanks!! Looked at ```Caffeine``` too, seems promising, would like to try soonish!!

Comment: another interesting piece of code, ```chm.put(key, System.currentTimeMillis()```, and this is done in a loop of avg size 100 for every request, i think better would be ```chm.get(key).setTime(System.currentTimeMillis())```. What say guys?

Comment: Obtaining the time is a native call and surprisingly expensive on some platforms (less so on Linux). If possible I'd pull it outside of the loop to avoid repeated calls.

Comment: reading carefully the javadoc for CHM in jdk8, i feel javadoc can be misleading sometime. In my codebase i have good number of lines of code using computeIfAbsent, although most of them are just initializing the value, but still very few do a slow computation which must be causing a lot of trouble. Thanks @Ben, this has been really helpful.

Comment: Profiling is not very simple. If some profiler shows that hotspot is here or there it does not always mean that it's actually there.

Comment: I agree @TagirValeev, a lot of common sense, application knowledge should be put in the profiling results. But just not being simple doesn't rule out getting value our of profiling.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap can handle about 4 million get/puts per second per thread and has a latency of around 250 nano-seconds.  You need to be doing an awful lot of operations to take 100 ms, which is an eternity for a computer. A modern CPU can perform billions of instructions in that time.

Comment: @AmmSokun have you figured out what went wrong?

Answer (score 4):

> I have around 80 threads concurrently reading from CHM.

The simplest things to do are

- if you have a CPU bound process, don't have more active threads than you have CPUs, otherwise this will only add overhead and if these threads hold a lock while not running, because you have too many threads, it will really not help.
- increase the number of partitions. You will want to have at least 4x the number of segments/partitions and you have threads accessing a single map. However, you will get strange behaviour in CHM if you access it with more than 40 threads due to the way cache coherency works.  I suggest using a more efficient data structure for higher degrees of concurrency. In Java 8 the concurrencyLevel is a hint, but it is better than leaving the default initialise size of 16.
- don't spend so much time in CHM.  Find a way to do useful work without hitting a shared resource and your threads will run much more efficiently.

If you have any latencies you can see in a low latency system, you have a problem IMHO.

Comment: ` you will get strange behaviour in CHM if you access it with more than 40 threads` May you elaborate on this one ? What would be the behavior ? After all the CHM is designed for concurrent access, isn't it ? Also I don't see any issue with a huge number of threads *reading* unless there are a lot of writers too.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev good point, reading shouldn't be a problem.  On systems with a large number of CPUs I have seen scalability issues with CHM when you have over 40 active threads hitting the same CHM.  This is most likely a hardware rather than software issue as the machine used multiple sockets. When we can have 40 threads on one socket, I suspect the problem will go away.

Comment: Thanks @Peter!! QQ: Another thing i found was when using CHM with key as java.util.TimeZone `get` takes a higher time than vs using CHM with String as key. Any thoughts on that? Is it related to collisions?

Comment: @AmmSokun The hash code for SimpleTimeZone is pretty poor however it could also be as it is not Comparable.  HashMap in Java 8 use a Tree for String keys however a linked list for collisions for a class like TimeZone.

Comment: But what about ZoneInfo class? TimeZone.getInstance() returns a ZoneInfo class obj.

Comment: @AmmSokun ZoneInfo is more has a more efficient/random hashCode(). If you are seeing problems it may be you have a lot of collisions. You can reduce the load factor to see if that helps.